# What is the convergence of this series?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n!)^3}{(3n)!}$. I proceeded with the ratio test to get $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(n+1!)^3}{(3(n+1))!} \cdot \frac{(3n)!}{(n!)^3} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(n+1)^3}{3(n+1)} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{3}=\infty $$. So, the ratio test says that this series diverges, but from what I have looked up, this series should converge. Is there something wrong in my calculations? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Check your algebra, $(3(n+1))! = (3n+3)! = (3n)!(3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3)$ so you get a ratio of $\frac{1}{27}$ for $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Ah, I see where I went wrong. I always get mixed up when it comes to factorials. Thanks for your help!

Comment: See [OEIS A$091683$](http://oeis.org/A091683) and [factorial sums](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FactorialSums.html).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, there is an algebra error that is easily fixed and convergence follows. For an alternative proof, write out

\begin{align*}
(3n)! &= \big(1 \cdot 2 \cdots n\big)\big((n + 1) \cdot (n + 2) \cdots 2n)\big) \big((2n + 1) \cdot (2n + 2) \cdots 3n\big) \\
&\ge n! \cdot (2^n n!) \cdot (3^n n!) \\
&= 6^n (n!)^3
\end{align*}
The inequality follows from the fact that $n + k \ge 2k$ for each $k \in [1, n]$ (giving $2^n$) and something similar for the last term. Hence, the series is bounded by the convergent geometric series $\sum_{n =1 }^{\infty} (1/6)^n$, which even gives rather rapid convergence.